# Keep rows in dataframe for the last n appearances of a value in a column

Tags: r

I have a fairly large dataframe with about ~1M columns, and I need to remove many rows from them. It is difficult to describe in the title alone, but easier to show an example and then explain:

```
temp = data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3), b = LETTERS[1:15])
temp
   a b
1  1 A
2  1 B
3  1 C
4  1 D
5  1 E
6  2 F
7  2 G
8  2 H
9  2 I
10 3 J
11 3 K
12 3 L
13 3 M
14 3 N
15 3 O
```

With this, I want to keep only the rows corresponding to the last 3 appearances of each unique number in column a. that is, I am trying to obtain a dataframe that looks like this:

```
my_final_df
   a b 
1  1 C
2  1 D
3  1 E
4  2 G
5  2 H
6  2 I
7  3 M
8  3 N
9  3 0
```

For my full dataframe, data anywhere besides the last 3 rows for a certain number in the 'a' column is noise, which is why I want to remove them. I think I need to create a boolean vector of some sort to do this, and then subset my_df with the boolean vector, but not sure how.

Comment: `as.vector(sapply(unique(temp$a), function(x) rev(which(temp==x))[1:3]))` will give you the indices of the data frame needed

Comment: thanks. this is great. works on temp very well, although it's pretty slow on my full 1M row dataframe. will see if i can speed it up

Comment: If you're racing then `data.table` or `dplyr` or something will probably pip me, but `temp[with(temp, ave(a==a, a, FUN=function(x) rev(seq_along(x)) <= 3) ),]` should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` we can group by `a` and select the last 3 rows using `slice` and `tail`.

```
library(dplyr)
temp %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  slice(tail(1:n(), 3))

#     a      b
#  <dbl> <fctr>
#1     1      C
#2     1      D
#3     1      E
#4     2      G
#5     2      H
#6     2      I
#7     3      M
#8     3      N
#9     3      O
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do this compactly in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(temp)[, tail(.SD, 3) , a]
#   a b
#1: 1 C
#2: 1 D
#3: 1 E
#4: 2 G
#5: 2 H
#6: 2 I
#7: 3 M
#8: 3 N
#9: 3 O
```

---

Or an option using `tidyverse` with `top_n`

```
library(tidyverse)
temp %>% 
    group_by(a) %>% 
    top_n( 3, rank(row_number()))
#     a      b
#   <dbl> <fctr>
#1     1      C
#2     1      D
#3     1      E
#4     2      G
#5     2      H
#6     2      I
#7     3      M
#8     3      N
#9     3      O
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `split` by `a` and then keep last three rows for each sub group

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(temp, temp$a), function(x) tail(x,3)))
#     a b
#1.3  1 C
#1.4  1 D
#1.5  1 E
#2.7  2 G
#2.8  2 H
#2.9  2 I
#3.13 3 M
#3.14 3 N
#3.15 3 O
```